# Rails jquery sortable not saving position correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a sortable table and it seems to work fine, however the order is slightly off when I refresh the page.  Basically everything will be correct and in its right spot except for the last row I moved, in which it usually reverts to one row beneath the row it should be occupying.  (Example: if I wanted the order to be 1,4,2,3 and the last box I moved into place was box 4; on refresh I get 1,2,4,3) Hopefully this makes sense.

My jquery:

```
jQuery ->
  if $('#sortable').length > 0
    table_width = $('#sortable').width()
    cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length
    desired_width = table_width / cells + 'px'
    $('.table td').css('width', desired_width)

    $('#sortable').sortable(
      axis: 'y'
      items: '.item'
      cursor: 'move'

      sort: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow')
      stop: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow')
      update: (e, ui) ->
        item_id = ui.item.data('item-id')
        console.log(item_id)
        position = ui.item.index() # this will not work with paginated items, as the index is zero on every page
        $.ajax(
          type: 'POST'
          url: '/stripboards/update_row_order'
          dataType: 'json'
          data: { stripboard: {stripboard_id: item_id, row_order_position: position } }
        )
    )
```

My controller:

```
class StripboardsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @stripboards = Stripboard.rank(:row_order).all
    end

    def new
        @stripboard = Stripboard.new
    end

    def edit
        @stripboard = Stripboard.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @stripboard = Stripboard.new(stripboard_params)


        if @stripboard.save
            redirect_to stripboards_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @stripboard = Stripboard.find(params[:id])
        @stripboard.destroy

        redirect_to stripboards_path
    end

    def update_row_order
        @stripboard = Stripboard.find(stripboard_params[:stripboard_id])
        @stripboard.row_order_position = stripboard_params[:row_order_position]
        @stripboard.save

        render nostripboard: true # this is a POST action, updates sent via AJAX, no view rendered
    end

    private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_stripboard
        @stripboard = Stripboard.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def stripboard_params
        params.require(:stripboard).permit(:stripboard_id, :title, :scene, :scene_type, :location, :description, :time, :pages, :characters, :production_id, :row_order_position)
    end
end
```

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="sortable">
  <tr>
    <th class="col-sm-1">Scene #:</th>
    <th class="col-sm-1">INT/EXT:</th>
    <th class="col-sm-1">Time:</th>
    <th class="col-sm-4">Set:</th>
    <th class="col-sm-2">Location:</th>
    <th class="col-sm-1">Pages:</th>
    <th class="col-sm-2">Characters</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% @stripboards.each do |stripboard| %>
    <tr data-item-id=<%= "#{stripboard.id}" %> class="item" style="
      <% if stripboard.time == 2 && stripboard.scene_type == 1 %>background-color:#FFFFFF;<% end %>
      <% if stripboard.time == 2 && stripboard.scene_type == 2 %>background-color:#FFFF00;<% end %>
      <% if stripboard.time == 4 && stripboard.scene_type == 1 %>background-color:#00008B;color:#FFF;<% end %>
      <% if stripboard.time == 4 && stripboard.scene_type == 2 %>background-color:#006400;color:#FFF;<% end %>
      <% if stripboard.time == 1 %>background-color:#FFC0CB;<% end %>
      <% if stripboard.time == 3 %>background-color:#F4A460;<% end %>
      ">
      <td class="col-sm-1"><%= stripboard.scene %></td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <% if stripboard.scene_type == 1 %>INT<% end %>
        <% if stripboard.scene_type == 2 %>EXT<% end %>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1">
        <% if stripboard.time == 1 %>Morning<% end %>
        <% if stripboard.time == 2 %>Day<% end %>
        <% if stripboard.time == 3 %>Evening<% end %>
        <% if stripboard.time == 4 %>Night<% end %>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-4"><%= stripboard.title %><br /><%= stripboard.description %></td>
      <td class="col-sm-2"><%= stripboard.location %></td>
      <td class="col-sm-1"><%= stripboard.pages %></td>
      <td class="col-sm-1"><%= stripboard.characters %></td>
      <td class="col-sm-2"><%= link_to 'Delete', stripboard_path(stripboard), class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm",
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Confirm you want to permanently delete this strip.  This action cannot be undone, and will delete all data associated with this strip.' }  %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

My DB:

```
create_table "stripboards", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "scene"
    t.integer  "scene_type",    limit: 255
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "description"
    t.integer  "time",          limit: 255
    t.string   "pages"
    t.string   "characters"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "production_id"
    t.integer  "row_order"
    t.integer  "stripboard_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recognize the code from http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/. I just got it working for myself :)

In the `update_row_order` function you've renamed, I'm guessing accidentally, the `nothing` symbol to `nostripboard`. Bit of find-and-replace on "thing" gone wild, perhaps?

Try updating the last line so that the function reads like so:

```
def update_row_order
  @stripboard = Stripboard.find(stripboard_params[:stripboard_id])
  @stripboard.row_order_position = stripboard_params[:row_order_position]
  @stripboard.save

  render nothing: true # this is a POST action, updates sent via AJAX, no view rendered
end
```

The `render nothing: true` part tells Rails to just render nothing - use no views, no templates, simply respond with a HTTP 200 OK status.

Since I see no other problems with your code, try this and report back. I'd also advise using the Network tab of the dev console/dev tools in your favorite browser (I know Firefox and Chrome have one, haven't really tried in others). It will allow you to sniff the traffic send by AJAX and will mark, for example, 500 status responses. Also you should read the development server's logs and look for errors in there too - I'm almost sure there'll be an error if you look in there.